# Django - static files is not working

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. I want to add my CSS file in template/index.html, but I don't know how to do it except in DEBUG mode.

Project name: mercury

App name: gamma

/root/workspace/django/mercury/mercury/settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/root/workspace/django/mercury/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/root/workspace/django/mercury/bootstrap/dist/',
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

/root/workspace/django/mercury/gamma/templates/gamma/index.html

```
<link href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Full path of the originally dashboard.css file

```
/root/workspace/django/mercury/bootstrap/dist/css/dashboard.css
```

After running 'python manage.py collectstatic'
    /root/workspace/django/mercury/static/css/dashboard.css

The output:

```
[20/Oct/2017 12:27:48] "GET /static/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 98
```

I'm missing something?

I tried numerous things but didn't helped.

Thanks in advance!

## [Solution]

This is what I did to resolve my problem for those who are curious:

## Install Apache/Httpd + mod_wsgi

```
$ yum install httpd mod_wsgi
```

## Edit the htppd config

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf`

```
Alias /static /root/workspace/django/mercury/static
<Directory /root/workspace/django/mercury/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /root/workspace/django/mercury>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess gamma python-path=/root/workspace/django/mercury:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup gamma
WSGIScriptAlias / /root/workspace/django/mercury/mercury/wsgi.py
```

## Disable debug mode in settings.py

`DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static files need to be served by your webserver. The point of using static files is, that a webserver is faster to deliver the file, if it does not need to pass through django. So you need to make sure, that your webserver serves `/root/workspace/django/mercury/static/` at the url `/static/`.

In DEBUG mode you can serve static files with the code snippet posted by @sandeep-balagopal, so they work with `manage.py runserver` when you're debugging.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/) for more details.

Comment: I thought that Django will resolve the webserver part for me.
Thank you very much, I installed httpd and configure it and now it works.